# field updates in process builder firing triggers

Tags: trigger, workflow, flow, process-builder

If a condition in process builder executes multiple field updates (lets say 3) do the triggers fire after every single update (3 times) or just once?

Comment: it will fire 3 times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tested it in a Dev. org. and it appears to fire the triggers 3 times.

Surprised me as I thought it would execute them in bulk, but I haven't use PB much.

Comment: Yep - every Process Builder Action is its own Flow Element.

Comment: tested again. If one has 3 separate actions - triggers are invoked 3 times. If there are 3 fields updated in one action there is only one trigger call.